# $A_1, A_2 \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, symmetric and nonsingular matrix. Prove $A_1,A_2$ are not congruent $\implies A_1,A_2$ simultaneously diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

$A_1, A_2 \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, symmetric and nonsingular matrix.

Prove $A_1,A_2$ are not congruent $\implies A_1,A_2$ simultaneously diagonalizable by congruence.

I know that $\exists P_1,P_2$ such that $P_1^tA_1P_1=D_1 , P_2^tA_2P_2=D_2$ fordiagonal matrices $D_1,D_2$ but I don't understand why $P_1=P_2$.

Help please .

Thanks !

Comment: @user1551 By congruence

Comment: Hint: if two nonsingular $2\times2$ real symmetric matrices are not congruent, one of them must be (positive or negative) definite.